# How to fix the error "Unsupported type 'uses-permission'" in the Android Manifest file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-permissions

I'm following an Android MySQL tutorial (https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/#Creating-Helper-Classes) and the aim is to build an Android app connected to a MySQL database on an Apache server (XAMPP package). I use Android Studio (3.0.1) in order to develop the Android part.

I get an issue when I try to run the code, in my Android Manifest file (which allows the app to access the internet). The error is "Unsupported type 'uses-permission'" as said in the title. I've tried to look for common mistakes such as misspellings or if the permission I was asking for in my code indeed existed, but I couldn't find anything useful to fix it. And I didn't ask on the website of the tutorial because it looks pretty unlikely that I would get an answer (the last comment on the tutorial was on October 28th 2015), I've also looked at the comments and nobody seems to have got a similar issue.

Here is the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ch.jemili.yasmina.myheroapp">

    <!-- this is the internet permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What you have looks fine. Where is this error message appearing, and are you sure that it is complaining about your manifest?

Comment: have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your app?

Comment: @CommonsWare there is the following message on the console :   "*What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/Yasmina/AndroidStudioProjects/MyHeroApp/app/src/main/res/values/AndroidManifest.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'uses-permission' "

Comment: @SaraTirmizi can you explain what you mean by "cleaning", please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, you have a manifest file in `app/src/main/res/values/AndroidManifest.xml` in your project. That is not where the manifest goes. The manifest goes in `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.